# Regex that covers all of the following listed URL's

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, .htaccess

I need a regular expression that will cover all of these, the segments are not always the named the same or in the same order or length.

This is for an Apache rewrite rule that will remove

```
index.php/module/action/param1/asset/css/static/js/jquery/signup/asset/rss/
```

From

`https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/asset/css/static/js/jquery/signup/asset/rss/comment-note`

If it is present

So input is
`https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/help/rss/legal/rss/comment-picture`

Output needed
`https://example.com/comment-picture`

I need to do this for all thes URL examples plus any random variation of them.
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/blog/rss/blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/help/faq
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/xml/sitemap/rss/comment-blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/b/rss/blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/help/rss/legal/rss/comment-picture
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/signup/static/js/jquery/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/asset/css/legal/help/xml/rss/comment-blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/note/main/xml/sitemap/rss/partners
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/xml/sitemap/rss/forum-topic
    /index.php/module/action/param1/rss/static/js/jquery/asset/css/game/category/casino
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/blog/main/rss/comment-picture
    /index.php/module/action/param1/asset/css/static/js/jquery/signup/static/css/rss/templates/system/modules/blog/themes/rss/note
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/legal/rss/rss/comment-note
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/static/js/geo/rss/rss/rss/blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/asset/css/static/js/jquery/signup/dating/rss/rss/comment-blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/rss/b/xml/rss/rss/rss/rss/note
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/xml/rss/rss/blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/rss/b/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/comment-blog
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/signup/static/js/jquery/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/asset/css/legal/legal/user/birthday-people/rss/comment-video
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/legal/invite/home/xml/sitemap/xmllink
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/xml/rss/help/static/js/jquery/rss/forum-topic
    /index.php/module/action/param1/asset/css/static/js/jquery/signup/asset/rss/comment-note
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/rss/blog/main/rss/rss/b/rss/rss/blog/category/rss/note
    /index.php/module/action/param1/static/PFBC/js/jquery/rss/static/css/js/jquery/smoothness/templates/themes/datelove/img/icon/xml/sitemap/user/xml/rss/help/game/main/search
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/user/rss/legal/legal/profile/xml/rss/rss/forum-topic
    /index.php/module/action/param1/legal/asset/css/asset/signup/forum/forum/legal/user/birthday-people/dating/rss/comment-picture

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: It would be loads more helpful to answer if you provided some relevant inputs and their corresponding outputs, along with any specific conditions you want to match.

Comment: @Undefined-Variables All you've done is provide the outputs, with no connection to their inputs. What's the common pattern to all the desired results? Do you want to extract every index.php file, or should there be some specific folders within that? It's always better to post minimal and verifiable examples.

Comment: What would be the output if the input is `https://example.com/index.php/module/action/param1/asset/css/static/js/jquery/signup/asset/rss/help/faq/finalform`?

Comment: Output would be `https://example.com/finalform`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you can use to select the parts you **want to remove**:

```
(?:http(?:s|):\/\/)?(?:www.)?(?:.*?\..*?\/)(.*\/)(?=.*?)
```

As seen **[here](https://regex101.com/r/ijoaK4/1)**

***Group 1*** of the 1st match contains all the extraneous parts that you want to remove, so you can use some replace function for that.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have no idea the headache you have just solved :)

Comment: @Undefined-Variables No problem! If you feel this answer has solved your problem, consider accepting it as  the correct answer by clicking the tick mark.

Comment: `(?:s|)` is better written `s?`. This regex is matching [wwww.//](https://regex101.com/r/ijoaK4/3)